# Connection String Issues With Entity Framework Context And Deleting

Tags: linqpad

I have a simple find delete case:

```
var query = CompanyUsers
 .Where ( cu => cu.eMail.Contains( "123@email.com") || cu.eMail.Contains( "456@email.com"))

ServicesEntities se = new ServicesEntities();
 se.DeleteObject( query );
```

ServiceEntities is a EntityFramework 4.1 DLL. The only thing in the DLL is the EF model.

When I try to delete I get:

"ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."

If I try adding the name of the connection string in the app.config file like this:

```
ServicesEntities se = new ServicesEntities("ServicesEntities");
```

I get: ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

How can I use my EF model and perform deletes using the conext. Is it possible to pass through the connection string that LINQPad appears to be creating in the properties tab or at the minimum use the one from the app.config?

Comment: Have you tried checking the connection string from within LINQPad? Run the query: this.Connection.ConnectionString, or if you're using a DbContext, this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString

Comment: If his problem is the same as mine, "this.Connection.ConnectionString" doesn't work because LINQPad throws that error while trying to initialize.